# Common method to check if a service is stopped

Tags: linux, service

I m looking for common method that check if a service is really stopped after executing `/etc/init.d/<service> stop`

Are there a common way for all services?

Comment: I just came across this again... Did my answer work to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can normally use

```
/etc/init.d/<service> status
```

Open the `/etc/init.d/<service>` file, they are normally very clear and easy to understand.

Also, you can check the processes with

```
ps -ef | grep <service>
```

but will not be that clear.